# Content controls in Word Document 2010

Tags: vsto, openoffice.org

Hi
I have a rich text control on the word document. I am using OpenXML to find the content control and set the data. 
Now i am setting some html markup to this rich content control. I was expecting to see some styling, instead i see the markup rendered as plain text.

Help needed

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply put html in a richtext content control and have it do something. `OpenXMl` styling is not HTML but rather XML as the name implies.
Check out these links:

[How do you change the content of a content control in Word 2007 with OpenXml SDK 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075505/how-do-you-change-the-content-of-a-content-control-in-word-2007-with-openxml-sdk)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.runstyle.aspx